# Combine two Django queries

Tags: django, django-orm

I have two related models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    pass


class Entry(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='entries')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I need to get categories with published entries.

I ended up with two queries:

```
published = Entry.objects.filter(is_published=True)
categories = Category.objects.filter(entries__in=published)
```

Can I do this in one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the double-underscore to make a query across related objects.

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(entry__is_published=True)
```

(Note, your original code would actually only do one query, but it would have a subquery which is likely to be less efficient than the JOIN in my version.)

Comment: vlad because your field name is entries not entry, you have to understand the code don't copy and paste!

Comment: @Daniel there is a typo in your query, but the idea is correct, thanks.